# Before OOP, how were systems modeled

Tags: modeling, paradigms

Before the advent of OOP, how were systems modeled in other paradigms of  Programming.

Obviously, software programs existed prior to 1970's and they interacted with people and where used in crucial places.

How did early programming paradigm tackle the problem of modeling data.

Comment: Your question presumes that OO is the only way to effectively model a system.  It isn't.  The Linux Kernel is written in C, which only has `struct`.  Git is also written in C.  Purely functional programming languages don't have OO, not in the sense you are speaking about.

Comment: There is a ton of information about the history of computing and programming languages.  We can't effectively distill it down in one answer.  Perhaps search for the history of programming language paradigms and you'll find that there is a whole lot more than just procedural and OOP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If we look at it more closel, even though C does not help OOP, parts of the Linux kernel still follow the paradigm.

Comment: In the 1970s, a more limited number of problems were computerised, a lot more was available to be spent on development and on the calibre of developers (because computers often replaced fully-manual, labour-intensive systems for the first time, rather than just being replacements or augmentations for existing systems), and very often the business was simplified or reorganised to comply with the needs of the new computer system. And far fewer resources were spent on testing, documentation, or future flexibility.

Comment: Alan Kay once said in a talk that the oldest code he found that we would today recognize as "object-oriented" was in a paper from 1953. It was written in assembly, not an OO language, but it still had everything we would expect today: message sending, encapsulation, polymorphism. Entities solving problems by collaborating via message passing, delegation, etc. Let me repeat that: **1953**.

Comment: that is wild @JörgWMittagm, So i guess every imperative paradigm language can be written in OOP style but it's just easier with languages that support it natively, am i right?

Comment: For some definition of "easier."

Comment: Systems in the past were modeled the same way as non-OO systems (or non-purely OO systems) are modeled today: using data structures, functions which operate on them, smaller and larger modules, libraries, sometimes utilizing event-mechanics, and so on.

Comment: The question is interesting.  The last sentence sounds however terribly subjective ("judged inadequate"). Could you try to reformulate in a more neutral way (e.g. "was preferred for", or "was superseded by") ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm pondering whether OP specifically meant reference types, rather than "objects" in the more abstract sense (i.e. existentially). Because I would consider a struct to be a (primitive) form of the latter - which would render your comment somewhat moot, no? Or am I glossing over an important distinction?

Comment: Instead of thinking about class hierarchies, you *simply write down what the computer should do*. ("simply" in air quotes)

Comment: @Flater: A `struct` in C is simply a container for composite data.  It doesn't have any of the other hallmarks of OO like inheritance, and the functions that operate on that data are kept elsewhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Everything you say is correct, but I was focusing on OP's intention. He's asking about _data modeling_, which suggests the possibility that OP means classes (as data objects) instead of full blown OOP. If so, then structs would sort of satisfy that (as they are valid data containers, albeit lacking in other OOP features)

Answer (score 9):

It would be pretty silly to think that we didn't have objects before OOP.

OOP formalizes a notion of class, which allows arguably superior code organization.  But these same constructs can be done in assembly or C.  Further, tagged structures with switch statements also provide the equivalent functionality of classes, subclasses, and overrides, though considerably less formally.

The 68k-based Macintosh computers used a lot of assembly (in part as compilers just weren't as good 40 years ago).

We have always had a way to group fields together into an object.

FORTRAN '66 — notably lacking a formal construct of structure or record — programmers would simply use parallel arrays where the separate arrays held the various fields of interest, and same index position in each separate array constituted an object.

There's always (and always been) some way to compose fields into an object, to relate one object to another, to substitute one object for another, to handle one object differently than another.

Comment: So i guess every imperative paradigm language can be written in OOP style but it's easier to implement with languages that support it natively, am i right?

Comment: Yes.  You can write OOP in assembly; ilike anything in assembly, it is error prone, so lots of fun!

Comment: C structs with data and callbacks as function pointers is used quite wildly inside the Linux kernel, at least the subsystems I learned about, like I2C or buses

Comment: I find this answer particularly biased towards OOP. No, before OOP people weren't just simulating OOP without OOP.

Comment: @user253751, you're kidding yourself if you think that before formal enums, record types, programmers didn't have ways of doing tagged unions and "objects".  For example, an old filesystem might have directory entries, with name, date, (etc..), and integer representing whether file or sub-directory.  If file, then handle like this, if directory, then handle like that depending on the application.  We've always had enums, sum types, product types in concept even when not supported by dedicated language constructs.

Comment: @user253751, ok, but that's putting words in my mouth.  Maybe you should write an answer to this post to make your position clear.

Comment: It's 4 years later and you are still trying to convince me that OOP is all there has ever been and for a while there just weren't languages that had it built-in.

Comment: @user253751, not true, just saying that there was objects before OOP.  You can dispute that or elaborate on how there's always been more than OOP with your own answer to this question.

Comment: @user253751, right and today, as well, not just back then, we use approaches other than OOP.  Remember, thought that the OP is the one that put OOP in the question title, so it is fundamental to the answer.

Comment: @user253751, yes, hence my answer.  Anyone can play here, so why don't you write your own answer to elucidate us?

Comment: @ErikEidt I have already upvoted suitable answers, no need to write my own.

Answer (score 6):

OOP is actually *more* limited as far as modeling is concerned. The reason is every verb *must* be tightly coupled to exactly one noun. Other paradigms don't have that limitation. You don't have to make inane decisions like whether to do `item.addToCart(cart)` or `cart.addItem(item)`. You can have an `addItemToCart(item, cart)`.

Comment: THis is a perfectly valid comment.  But how does it answer the question ?

Answer (score 6):

Before OOP, the [**structured programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) paradigm used to separate processes and data.

This separation also applied for modelling:

- Processes used to be modelled with [dataflow diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_diagram) (the most famous were Yourdon&Coad and Gane&Sarson) or [functional decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_analysis_and_design_technique) models (like *Structured Analysis & Design Technique* aka SADT aka [IDEF0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0));
- Data was modelled using [entity-relelationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) models, and in some environments with IDEF1 (deprecated by an OO [IDEF1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X)).

Note that ERD, and to a lesser extent IDEF0, are still in use today.

Note also that OO is not an end and the only a mean to construct complex systems.  If you look at the size of the code of an operating system you'll be surprised how complex it is, and there is still little OO in there.

Comment: Great answer. Btw, is a struct part of the specification of procedural paradigm?

Comment: @EdgeDev do you mean data struct ? indeed, typical structured programming languages such as Pascal or Modula2, or typical procedural programming languages like [ADA](https://www.embedded.com/introduction-to-ada-95/) (before objects were introduced in it) already worked with types and data structures ([records in ADA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/record) and in [modula2](https://www.modula2.org/tutor/chapter10.php))